# Asking for a users timezone and putting that info into date_default_timzone_set()

Tags: php, timezone

I am making a web app that is going to ask the user for his/her timezone in a dropdown. The only dropdowns I have found are ones with the values equal to the number or w/e of the timezone (for example: -8 for PST) I would use this but I need to be able to put it into date_default_timezone_set() and that number wont work... I will need something like "America/Los_Angeles" as the value.

How could I find a list like this or convert that "-8" to this string?

I am also open to other ways of going about this. The basic idea of the app is to show the users schedule and show what time it is currently and when their next tasks are, so that is why I will need the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GMT-08:00`. Given -8 you can easily construct this string with sprintf.

The time zone offset is not enough because of daylight savings time. For example most of Europe is currently at GMT+02:00, but at GMT+01:00 in winter.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I find a list like this or convert that "-8" to this string?

You can't. There are lots of time zones which might currently observe the same UTC offset, or which share the same "standard time" offset but vary in terms of whether or when they observe daylight savings.

You need to find a different dropdown library - one which includes the place as well as the current offset. I'd expect such a library to already have the IANA ID as the "value" passed back to the server.